# Why do `prev = poss[0]` and `prev = 0` behave differently?

Tags: python

I have a question about this code:

```
    poss = [6,9,20]

for n in range(6,66):
    if(n%6) == 0 or (n%9) == 0 or (n%20) == 0:
        poss.append(n)
poss.sort()
count = 0
prev = poss[0] 

for p in poss:
    print p
    if prev == p:
        del poss[count]
    count += 1
    prev = p

print poss
```

The 2nd for loop is intended to get rid of duplicates in the poss list and this code works correctly.  However, if I change the line:

```
prev = poss[0]
```

to

```
prev = 0
```

it won't correctly delete them.  For the life of me, I can't figure out why.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Don't mutate the list you are looping over. This is just guaranteed to lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make poss into a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to remove the duplicates? E.g.

```
poss = set(poss)
```

To answer your original question, `prev = poss[0]` is not the same as `prev = 0` because `poss[0]` is not 0.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that your second loop does not remove duplicates.  I'm really not sure what it will do since you are modifying the list that you are iterating over and skipping values every time that you delete.  I recommend using any of the following:

```
# this is the same list w/o duplicates, this can replace the entire snippet
poss = [ n for n in range(6, 66) if (n % 6) == 0 or (n % 9) == 0 or (n % 20) == 0 ]

# transform your input list into a set to remove dups
poss = list(sorted(set(poss))
```

No need for the `for` loop to remove the duplicates.  You can remove the `sorted` part if you do not need the result in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, your condition `prev == p` in the second for-loop is never met if `prev = 0`. I agree with others who suggested using `set()`.

Answer (score -2):

You also can use a [dictionnary](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to remove duplicates ([More info](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list)):

```
poss = list({p:None for p in poss}.keys()) # for python 3.x
```

or

```
poss = list({}.fromkeys(poss).keys())
```

But you will need to sort again the list (So sort it only one time, after removing duplicates).

`poss[0]` is 6 in your example, so `prev = 0` is different of `prev = poss[0]`.

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions are not available in Python 2.x, which is what it appears he is using.